# Finding out about pip or conda installations

Tags: python, anaconda

I have installed some packages using pip and others using conda, how can I see which is which (conda or pip installed)? Also, is there a way for me to change them from conda to pip or vise versa?

Comment: At least for pip, you can `pip list` to see what's installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just type:

```
conda list
```

This will list all installed packages. The ones installed with pip are indicated as such. The last column contains `<pip>`.

For example:

```
yaml                      0.1.6                         0  
yarl                      0.10.2                    <pip>
```

Comment: if a package is installed using both `pip` and `conda` is there a way to check which version is being used when imported?

Comment: A package can be installed only once. Therefore, installing with `pip` would replace the `conda`-installed package and vice versa. So, whatever method you used last would be the one installed. There is no difference when you import it.